# C# cannot see one table in my SQL Server - Invalid object name

Tags: c#, sql-server, razor

I've inherited a new web app project. It's a C#/ MVC Razor Engine project. I got my dev environment set up (Visual Studio & SQL Server Management Studio) & ran the code.

While querying the `PageSEO` table, I got this error:

> Invalid object name 'PageSEO'.

I got a fresh copy of the database, restored the database & get the same error. I can see the table in SSMS & I can query it there, but in the application, it throws an error.

Code:

```
d@{
    Page.Title = "Home";
    var ID = -1;
    var title = "";
    var desc = "";

    var db = Database.Open("XXX2013");
    var sqlCommand = "SELECT TOP 1 pressReleaseID, pressTitle, LEFT(pressText, 315) as shortdesc FROM PressReleases ORDER BY pressDate DESC";
    var featured = db.QuerySingle(sqlCommand);
    ID = featured["pressReleaseID"];
    title = featured["pressTitle"];
    desc = featured["shortdesc"];

    var sql2 = "SELECT * from PageSEO WHERE SEOPage = @0";

    //THIS IS TEST CODE to verify connection to other tables
    var sql3 = "SELECT * FROM Brokers WHERE brokerLast = @0";
    int x = db.Query(sql3, "Smith").Count();
    int y = x; 
    int y = x;
    //END TEST       
}

@section metas{

    @foreach (var page in db.Query(sql2, "Home"))   //ERROR IS THROWN HERE
    {
        <meta name="title" content="@page.SEOTitle" />
        <meta name="description" content="@page.SEODesc " />
        <meta name="keywords" content="@page.SEOKeywords" />
    }
}
```

I've double checked db names, column names, etc. The permissions are no different for this table. The only thing different about this table is that it was created recently, but when I do a restore, that shouldn't matter, should it?

Some things I've tried.

1. I dropped the table & created a new one just like it. Same issue.
2. I also deleted the entire database, created a new one & did a fresh restore & same issue.
3. On one test run, in the test section of code, I deliberately spelled the table name wrong & got the same error: Invalid object name 'BrokersX'
4. I have run the test code for every other table & get a record count for all of them.

Why can't C# see this table when it can see all the others? This table is referenced on almost every page.

Comment: What query & connection string are you running in SSMS?

Comment: When reproducing the error in SSMS, use the same login that you're using in your code. Double check the exact query string used.

Comment: `select '*' + name + '*' from sys.tables where name like '%ageSE%' `

Comment: You haven't included the schema name in your queries ([and you should](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)); are all the tables in the same schema?